# IE10 and bigger: is it possible to change the text-color of an select/option element?

Tags: html, css

I am having an simple `<select>` Element with multiple `<options>` nested within.

I am trying to change the text color by css like so:

```
select{
color: pink;
}

option{
color: pink;
}
```

Somehow these styles do not apply to Internet Explorer Version 10 and higher. Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: can you share that link in which you are trying? I think it must be overriding with some other style.

Comment: see the screenshot for my current dev environment

Comment: In your screenshot, you're applying the CSS to the select tag only. Try setting it on the option tag!

Comment: u can't see it on the screenshot, but I am already doing this

Answer (score 1):

What's your problem?
higher then IE10 No problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
select{
  color: pink;
  }

  option{
  color: pink;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <select>
    <option>HellO1</option>
    <option>HellO2</option>
    <option>HellO3</option>
    <option>HellO4</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see the screenshot for my current dev environment

Answer (score 0):

Its possible with

```
select::-ms-value {
   color: pink;
}
```